# Формула для нахождения количества комбинаций, исходя из количества кубиков и выпавшего результата

Tags: java, комбинаторика

нужна помощь в написании функции diceRoll(int dices, int result) , которая получает два аргумента, первый - количество кубиков, второй - результат который выпал. Собственно, проблема состоит в составлении формулы подсчета комбинаций выпадения x результата при n - количестве кубиков, где, например (1+5) и (5+1) - разные комбинации.
Например, при
diceRoll(2, 5) -> 4
//(1 + 4)(4 + 1)(2 + 3)(3 + 2)
Или, может быть можно как-нибудь решить без формулы? Пока не получается сообразить полный перебор :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам действительно нужно только **количество** подходящих комбинаций, то перебор, конечно, ни к чему.

Если поставить точки в количестве `result`, то между ними будет `result-1` мест, куда можно поставить `dices-1` разделителей, чтобы получить `dices` непустых частей.

```
o   o   o   o   o   o
  ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
  |   |   |   |   |
```

Таким образом, формула получается для [числа сочетаний из n по k](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

```
С(result-1,dices-1) = (result-1)! / ((result-dices)! * (dices-1)!)
```

Например, для 6,3 это C(5,2)=10. Проверяем:

```
1 1 4
1 2 3
1 3 2
1 4 1
2 1 3
2 2 2
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
4 1 1
```